# How to use the result of a function to another in asynchronous way

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have to make requests to a website to take the data, then I have to reformat it and send it to my database. I've already got the querying and sending to the database part right, but I need to make an infinite loop that will query every second and send the data to the database. Here is my loop code :

```py
import asyncio

async def get_Data_Campbell():
    # get data from website
    return data

async def insert_in_influx(data):
    # send data to influxdb
    ...

async def main():
    while True:
        # must be repeated every second 
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(get_Data_CampBell())

        # result of the task1
        res = await task1

        # no result needed
        task2 = asyncio.create_task(insert_in_Influx(res))
```

I was thinking of different ways but I can't find the right method to succeed.
Does anyone have any ideas? A functional method?

Comment: probably it would be simpler to run `insert_in_influx()` inside `get_Data_Campbell()`

Comment: your code works for me - it runs `get_Data_CampBell` every second - so it seems OK. It can make problem only if  `get_Data_Campbell` will run longer then 1s and it will not have code which use `await`